# How do I hide this top panel and where did my menu bar go?

Tags: interface

Please tell me how to hide the top panel. Dragging any of the corner handles up on the other panels does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick in this scenario is you have to collapse all the lower panels so that you have 2 horizontal panels, then join them to one and then start out again to create the layout you want.

[image]

Comment: Haha, got the same problem recently. It took me about 30 mins to figure it out :D.

Comment: Somebody should make a puzzle game out it. Sort of like a Rubic's cube puzzle, but with Blender panels.

Comment: Brilliant idea Todd! I've just designed the first stage of the game :D. Check it out: https://imageshack.com/i/pdFHQOF6j

Comment: @Gonzou Too easy. Probably wouldn't make me think very hard.

Comment: This was just a warm up ;). Here's the harder level: https://imageshack.com/i/exFMFI8Pj